# Interchanging DirectX 11 and DirectX 9 code

Tags: c++, hook, directx-11, directx-9

I'm currently developing a game for a system that has a requirement that any graphics processing be done through DirectX 9.  This is because the system itself needs to do its own graphical drawing over the top of any games that are running and I think it does this by hooking in to the present method IDirect3DDevice9::Present to interrupt our drawing to do its own.

The frustrating thing is the system has hardware capable of running games using DirectX 11 and I've had test applications running, but (I'm assuming because the Present call no longer exists in Dx11) doing so means the system can't hook in to a Present call and therefore can't show its own graphics.  Unfortunately the hook is fixed on the system and I'm unable to modify it.

So I was wondering if it was possible/feasible to design a game that used DirectX 11 and all its bells and whistles for graphics generation whilst using DirectX 9 to do the actual "drawing" of the graphics to screen.  I'm pretty new to graphics programming but if this type of thing is possible then it's something I'd like to look in to.

Any feedback/comments appreciated.

Comment: In Directx11, present is done via a dxgi swapchain, so it should be possible to hook this. Otherwise you can eventually use shared textures.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't modify the hook as its on the system, I have no control over that, I'll edit my question to reflect that.

Comment: Your only real option is [DXGI Surface Sharing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee913554.aspx) of a Direct3D 11 render target as a Direct3D 9 texture.

Comment: That would mean using a Dx11 pipeline to generate a Dx9 texture correct?  Presumably this means you'd still have to use a Dx11 Swap call rather than a Dx9 Present call?